# A Continuous Flood of Kernel Warnings. Am I under attack?

Tags: firewalls, logging, kernel

I have a Linksys WRT1200AC with DD-WRT v3.0-r48865 std. It's connected to the Internet through the ISP's modem in bridge mode.
My syslog reports continuously, many times per second stuff like this:

```
kern.warn kernel: [18453.515784] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=65.9.190.202 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=44071 SEQ=3670535760 ACK=0 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST
kern.warn kernel: [18453.536530] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=65.9.190.202 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=44071 SEQ=3670535760 ACK=0 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST
kern.warn kernel: [18453.557323] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=65.9.190.202 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=44071 SEQ=3670535760 ACK=0 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST
kern.warn kernel: [18453.582997] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:6c:56:97:7a:c6:0a:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.38 DST=65.9.190.202 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=63798 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=50718 DPT=443 SEQ=1243591697 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x
kern.warn kernel: [18454.250472] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:6c:56:97:7a:c6:0a:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.38 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=75 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=20859 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=12864 DPT=53 LEN=55
kern.warn kernel: [18454.312503] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:6c:56:97:7a:c6:0a:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.38 DST=65.9.191.142 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=15747 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=34206 DPT=443 SEQ=3221647603 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x
kern.warn kernel: [18454.456131] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=89.248.165.199 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=247 ID=50231 PROTO=TCP SPT=49471 DPT=7001 SEQ=1066431920 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x
kern.warn kernel: [18455.623531] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:6c:56:97:7a:c6:0a:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.38 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=75 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=20885 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=15773 DPT=53 LEN=55
kern.warn kernel: [18455.683639] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:6c:56:97:7a:c6:0a:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.38 DST=65.9.191.193 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=58387 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=45180 DPT=443 SEQ=1247652330 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x
kern.warn kernel: [18456.338016] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:28:16:a8:07:bd:0b:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.15 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=12701 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49677 DPT=443 SEQ=2484516485 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN
kern.warn kernel: [18456.642510] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=198.144.159.158 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=53335 PROTO=TCP SPT=57411 DPT=52206 SEQ=1618279 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x0
kern.warn kernel: [18456.803271] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:00:11:32:74:79:ea:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.11 DST=220.130.197.210 LEN=176 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=254 ID=1 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58619 DPT=443 LEN=156
kern.warn kernel: [18458.651647] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:28:16:a8:07:bd:0b:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.15 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=62 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=12709 PROTO=UDP SPT=65484 DPT=53 LEN=42
kern.warn kernel: [18458.675405] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:28:16:a8:07:bd:0b:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.15 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=62 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=12710 PROTO=UDP SPT=65484 DPT=53 LEN=42
kern.warn kernel: [18458.713954] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:28:16:a8:07:bd:0b:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.15 DST=2.22.22.120 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=4085 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49979 DPT=80 SEQ=2810023282 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00
kern.warn kernel: [18460.344775] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:28:16:a8:07:bd:0b:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.15 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=12711 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49980 DPT=443 SEQ=3643991877 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN
kern.warn kernel: [18460.744288] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=198.144.159.22 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=61600 PROTO=TCP SPT=57204 DPT=40630 SEQ=992068808 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x
kern.warn kernel: [18461.491148] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=198.144.159.22 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=13867 PROTO=TCP SPT=57209 DPT=41708 SEQ=3057794585 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0
kern.warn kernel: [18463.516372] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=198.144.159.158 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=2031 PROTO=TCP SPT=57406 DPT=49775 SEQ=3307171678 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0
kern.warn kernel: [18464.339010] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:28:16:a8:07:bd:0b:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.15 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=12719 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49981 DPT=443 SEQ=3554574726 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN
kern.warn kernel: [18464.479454] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=193.163.125.212 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=243 ID=12436 PROTO=TCP SPT=59369 DPT=8080 SEQ=2246553964 ACK=0 WINDOW=14600 RES=
kern.warn kernel: [18465.170741] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:9c:2a:83:2e:97:41:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.34 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=817 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=28513 DPT=53 LEN=40
kern.warn kernel: [18465.217568] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:9c:2a:83:2e:97:41:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.34 DST=142.250.180.196 LEN=1278 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=24091 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=49979 DPT=443 LEN=1258
kern.warn kernel: [18465.235464] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:9c:2a:83:2e:97:41:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.34 DST=142.250.180.196 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=30570 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53890 DPT=443 SEQ=3080202614 ACK=0 WINDOW=65535 RES
kern.warn kernel: [18465.883844] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:f0:23:b9:ec:18:90:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.10 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=59 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=7859 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=34860 DPT=53 LEN=39
kern.warn kernel: [18465.926934] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:f0:23:b9:ec:18:90:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.10 DST=52.48.161.79 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=51107 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=40604 DPT=443 SEQ=2042619947 ACK=0 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x
kern.warn kernel: [18466.811818] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:00:11:32:74:79:ea:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.11 DST=220.130.197.210 LEN=176 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=254 ID=1 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=58619 DPT=443 LEN=156
kern.warn kernel: [18468.341421] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:28:16:a8:07:bd:0b:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.15 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=12727 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=49982 DPT=443 SEQ=1677737286 ACK=0 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN
kern.warn kernel: [18469.439010] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=198.144.159.105 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=31319 PROTO=TCP SPT=57487 DPT=56235 SEQ=2723613474 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=
kern.warn kernel: [18469.817527] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=198.144.159.158 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=50607 PROTO=TCP SPT=57415 DPT=53035 SEQ=234922074 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0
kern.warn kernel: [18469.930601] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=198.144.159.158 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=11432 PROTO=TCP SPT=57411 DPT=51595 SEQ=3124514813 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=
kern.warn kernel: [18470.001633] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=198.144.159.110 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=21305 PROTO=TCP SPT=56948 DPT=24239 SEQ=3383273288 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=
kern.warn kernel: [18470.158831] DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=37.9.13.98 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=4854 PROTO=TCP SPT=10709 DPT=3389 SEQ=833533205 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0x00 SYN
kern.warn kernel: [18471.783041] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:00:11:32:74:79:ea:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.11 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=48933 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41090 DPT=53 LEN=50
kern.warn kernel: [18471.799506] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:00:11:32:74:79:ea:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.11 DST=10.0.0.1 LEN=70 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=48934 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=41090 DPT=53 LEN=50
kern.warn kernel: [18471.832356] ACCEPT IN=br0 OUT=eth0 MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:00:11:32:74:79:ea:08:00 SRC=10.0.0.11 DST=159.100.4.210 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=23602 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=56069 DPT=443 SEQ=828042105 ACK=0 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x
```

The first part of the long MAC address (cd:a4:21:a8:3b:a6) corresponds to my router, for the remaining part of it I have no clue. 94.253.170.222 is my current public IP, and my LAN is using 10.0.0.1/24. Is this log showing just the normal internet "noise" correctly handled by my firewall or should I be worried? The reason I wonder is that, with the log verbosity settings unchanged, I never had this much "chatter" before; it has only started recently.

Will appreciate any advice.

Comment: ACCEPT logs clearly indicate that there is lots of verbose logging enabled, because this is explicitly accepted traffic which gets logged. And even the DROP looks like normal traffic and a bit of the usual internet chatter to me - no real attacks here.

Comment: Look e.g. to this one: `DROP IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=c0:56:27:73:3d:d4:2c:0b:e9:15:a0:19:08:00 SRC=198.144.159.22 DST=94.253.170.222 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=245 ID=13867 PROTO=TCP SPT=57209 DPT=41708 SEQ=3057794585 ACK=0 WINDOW=1024 RES=0` Why is someone from an IP address in Canada trying to connect to my port 41708?

Comment: As I said *"... and a bit of the usual internet chatter ..."*. There is always something probing systems but this does not indicate that somebody is specifically attacking you.